# md5 generated code not showing google maps any more

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having a problem. I had a debug md5 code that was generated. I switched the code so I can publish my app, I now get a grey screen when i run my emulator. The map doesn't show up any more. Is this a problem? should i trying getting another md5 code to use? Or can the debug code work?

Answer (score 1):

You must generate another API code. Your Google Maps API code is generated based on the keys your app is signed with, therefore if you sign your app with release keys, you must generate an API code which is generated using the same release key.

Comment: So basically I should start over? Do another keystore and all, then repeat the steps to generate md5? Also, what is the reason for doing the debug in the first place? I can get the debuged one to work on the emulator and my phone... I'm a newbe at this...

Comment: Well, all you really need to do is go back through the process of generating your API key. I believe the reason they ask for your key is to stop the service being abused by apps, since they provide it for free. You can read about the differences between debug and release keys here - http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I've read the link. I'm still having the same problem. When you do this theres two files one is the apk file the other is the keystore file right? I have the name of the app on the apk, i wrote the keystore file as MapKey. I right click the keystore to get propertys and highlight the location of the keystore.

Comment: I do all the steps in cmd to get the md5 code. keytool -list -v -alias myalias -keystore :C\droidApps\MapKey -storepass mypass -keypass mypass. It then generates the md5 code, i then go to the site to post the md5 code and get the other code I'll use with the MapV layout.